# How will the development and experimental nature of Aeon improve the Monero protocol in the future?

Tags: aeon

It is well known Aeon is like the baby brother of Monero and will be used as a playground for experimentation, but what kind of things will be played around with?

Comment: Your question is both speculative and partially a duplicate. Aeon is on topic, so please ask another more specific question that has not been asked already.